# can I create a class dynamically with $? (dollar-sign)

Tags: php

In PHP sometimes it would be nice if I could define a function or a class with a variable name like

```
$myfunctionname="test";

function $myfunctionname(){
  //...
}
```

so it would create the function `test()`

or with classes too like:

```
$foo = bar;
class $foo {
  // lots of complicated stuff 
  // ...
}
```

but this doesen't work. **like this it would give parse errors!**

Is there a solution to this?

*(I know, this is not good practise, but just as a workaround, it would be handy)*

---

**EDIT: My actual problem:**
I have a framework with a migration process where every migration step is in a separate php include file in a folder.
Each file contains only one migration class that contains the name of the include file.
Because the class has to have that certain name, I would like to create the name of the class to a generic name that is created  by the filename constant `__FILE__`

Comment: Even if this is possible, if you actually do that... WAT.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php

Comment: @ToBe, I think he wants a variable class name, not calling a class using a variable

Comment: @ToBe that creates a new object based on a class already defined. Not define a class with a dynamic name...

Comment: @Prisoner yep. Recipe for a messy code.

Comment: oh. wow ... just wow. Please show us a case where this would actually be desirable.

Comment: Er... The code you put as example of what supposedly can already be done triggers *Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$myfunctionname' (T_VARIABLE), expecting '(* :-?

Comment: @ToBe generating classes based on some template (think: `Struct`)? The class builder gets a class name passed in as an argument, along with other instructions on how to create the class.

Comment: Are you wanting to create an anonymous class?

Comment: As you can see from all the responses: even if it is possible, you don't want that. Don't anger your colleagues, they will hate you for it if you write code like that. It is a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: @ToBe: I added an example, why I am asking

Comment: There might be better alternatives. Im available for chat atm if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but I dont want you to.

```
$classname = "test";

eval("class {$classname}{ public function hello(){ echo \"hello!\"; } }");

$evil_class = new $classname();
$evil_class->hello(); // echo's "hello!"
```

now, if you don't mind me I'm going for a shower.

Comment: oh lord. You had to show him `eval` as if what he was doing wasn't bad enough already ;)

Comment: @crush hahaha, I know. I just dont think PHP has bad enough of a reputation already.

Comment: +1 for making it work; -1 for using `eval()`. OP is going to create a flying spaghetti monster of an app.

Comment: I'll se if there's a way without `eval`

Comment: @EdCottrell: as we all know, PHP is acronym for Programmable Hyperlinked Pasta, so it's quite appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a factory pattern:

```
class poly_Factory {  
  public function __construct() {  
      $class = 'poly';  
        return new $class();  
  }  
}
```

If that is anything you want to get to.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/understanding-and-applying-polymorphism-in-php/
Scroll down to step 4, last part...

I know you did not ask for that, but what can your question be good for else?

Comment: Patterns is actually the only reasonable way to do it. Also check Decorator and/or Strategy.

Comment: I don't think you should do this in a constructor though!

Comment: @ToBe Hmm, yeah well, you got ME on that one...I prepared nicely with SOLID and shit, but I still wonder how to prevent doing spaghetti code procedural mess while calling the classes, so I thought up a process of having a "web" of classes which call automatically the next node. I even wanted to show him passing the variable for `$class` with `$bar = new poly_Factory('poly');`. Would like to chat about that. Actual chat?

Answer (score 0):

No.  This code throws a parse error on line 3 because of the `$`:

```
$foo = 'bar';

class $foo {
    function hello() {
        echo "World";
    }
}

$mybar = new bar();
$mybar->hello();
```

Result:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_STRING on line 3

And as Jan Dvorak pointed out in the comments: even if you figure out a way to do this, *don't do this*.

Comment: this stinks of "variable variables", which should be avoided like the plague.

Comment: @JanDvorak This is what OP asked; I don't know of any other way one could do a variable class name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a value object you can just use the stdClass builtin type.

```
$object = new stdClass;
$object->someValue = "Hello World";
echo $object->someValue;
```

[See it in Action](http://3v4l.org/tqShB)

If you want to assign methods then you have to use the magic __call function, here is how I would do it.

```
class AnonObject{
    private $properties = array();
    private $methods = array();

    public function __get($property){
        return array_key_exists($property, $this->properties)?$this->properties[$property]:null;
    }

    public function __set($property, $value){
        if (!is_string($value) && is_callable($value)){
            if ($value instanceof \Closure){
                // bind the closure to this object's instance and static context
                $this->methods[$property] = $value->bindTo($this,get_class($this));
            } else {
                // invokable objects 
                $this->methods[$property] = $value;
            }            
        } else {
            $this->properties[$property] = $value;
        }
    }

    public function __call($method, $args){
        if (array_key_exists($method, $this->methods)){
            call_user_func_array($this->methods[$method], $args);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Method ".$method." does not exist on object");
        }
    }
}
```

[See it In Action](http://3v4l.org/1uv6H)

Note, as stated by several other people this is bad practice. If the goal of this exercise is to compose the behavior of an instance of an object at runtime a more maintainable solution would be to use the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)